# Solr local parameter for Tagging and Excluding Filters is not working

Tags: solr

Here I'm trying to get the count of most frequent items in a time range, vs items in all time:

```
{
    "query": "{!tag=time}time_in_seconds:[1589453460 TO 1589539860]",
    "facet": {
        "topItems": {
            "type": "field",
            "limit": 10,
            "field": "item_name",
            "facet": {
                "allItems": {
                    "type": "query",
                    "q": "{!ex=time}*:*"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, in the query result, topItems count is always the same with allItems count, since excluding filters is somehow not working:

```
"facets": {
    "count": 8263088,
    "topItems": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "val": "item 1",
          "count": 14945,
          "allItems": {
            "count": 14945
          }
        },
        {
          "val": "item 2",
          "count": 14060,
          "allItems": {
            "count": 14060
          }
        }...
```

From what I understand in [docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/faceting.html#tagging-and-excluding-filters), the inline facet should show total item count without the time filter. I am sure there are additional items outside of that time range.

Btw using Solr v. 8.4

-- Tried this too:

```
{
    "query": "*:*",
    "filter":["{!tag=time}time_in_seconds:[1589453460 TO 1589539860]"]
    "facet": {
        "topItems": {
            "type": "field",
            "limit": 10,
            "field": "item_name",
            "facet": {
                "allItems": {
                    "type": "query",
                    "q": "{!ex=time}*:*"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result is the same sadly.

Comment: The tag should be applied to a filter query (`fq` in regular queries, `filter` in JSON queries), not the main query. The facets will always consider the main query (the root domain) - as that's the result set the facets are generated from.

Comment: I tried like as I added to my question, but result is the same ..

Answer (score 1):

Digged a bit more into the docs, apparently it must be done like this:

```
{
"query": "*:*",
"filter": [{"#time":"time_in_seconds:[1589453460 TO 1589539860]"}],
"facet": {
    "topItems": {
        "type": "field",
        "limit": 10,
        "field": "item_name",
        "facet": {
            "allItems": {
                "type": "query",
                "q": "*:*",
                "domain": {"excludeTags":"time"}
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```